# Casting into CheckBoxFor HTMLHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, casting

I'm working on an editorTemplate, the goal of which is to take a value, display its label, and then select the appropriate control to place alongside it.

```
@model object

if (Model is bool)
        {
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.? , new { @class = @ViewData["class"], style = @ViewData["style"], id = @ViewData["id"] })
        }
```

I want to take the model, and stick it in that checkbox as a bool.

m => (bool)m does not work nor does m => m, nor does "m => m.As<>"
CheckboxFor will not accept a plain object, and if I do the conversions I get the following

```
Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access, 
property access, single-dimension array index, or 
single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

What is my best approach here, A new helper? other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="nameofproperty" checked='@(Model.nameofproperty == 1 ? true : false)' id="yourid"   value="1" />
```

in checked you can cast your object.